# Symfony Doctrine entity overview

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Is it possible to get a report of all the mapped entities in a project?

I would like a console command or an external bundle which could show me the detailed list of all the mapped entities, along with every detail about fields, types, constraints and so on.

Something like this:

### Product

```
|-------|-------------|--------|----------|-------------|
| Field | Type        | Column | Nullable | Constraints |
|-------|-------------|--------|----------|-------------|
| name  | string(255) | name   | no       | NotBlank    |
|-------|-------------|--------|----------|-------------|
| price | float       | price  | yes      | GreaterThan |
|-------|-------------|--------|----------|-------------|
```

It could be very useful to get a rapid overview of a project with many entities.

Comment: what do you mean could explain more

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031534/get-array-list-of-entities-from-doctrine

Comment: also https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html

Comment: I added more details: `I would like a console command or an external bundle which could show me the detailed list of all the mapped entities, along with every detail about fields, types, constraints and so on.`

Comment: You can create your own console commands.   If you use the link above, you can put something like that into a command:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-cli-commands-using-the-symfony-console-component--cms-31274

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation https://abendstille.at/blog/?p=163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can it help?

```
<?php

    namespace App\Command;

    use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table;

    class EntitylistCommand extends Command
    {

        protected static $defaultName = 'EntitylistCommand';

        protected function configure()
        {
            $this
                    ->setDescription('EntitylistCommand')
                    ->setHelp('EntitylistCommand');
        }
        public function __construct(ObjectManager $em)
        {
            $this->em = $em;

            // you *must* call the parent constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }
        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {

            /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
            $em = $this->em;
            $tables = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
            foreach ($tables as $table) {

                $tablename = $table->getName();
                echo $tablename . PHP_EOL;

                $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($tablename);
                $fields = $metadata->getFieldNames();
                $rows = array();
                foreach ($fields as $field) {

                    $fieldinfo = $metadata->fieldMappings[$metadata->getFieldName($field)];
                    $fieldname = $fieldinfo["fieldName"];
                    $fieldcolumnname = $fieldinfo["columnName"];
                    $fieldnullable = (isset($fieldinfo["nullable"]) ? ($fieldinfo["nullable"] ? "yes" : "no") : "no");
                    $fieldlength = (isset($fieldinfo["length"]) ? " (" . $fieldinfo["length"] . ")" : "");
                    $fieldtype = (isset($fieldinfo["type"]) ? $fieldinfo["type"] : "");

                    $rows[] = array($fieldname, $fieldtype . $fieldlength, $fieldcolumnname, $fieldnullable);
                }

                $table = new Table($output);
                $table
                        ->setHeaders(['Field', 'Type', 'Column', 'Nullable', 'Constraints'])
                        ->setRows($rows)
                ;
                $table->render();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| Field               | Type         | Column                | Nullable | Constraints |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| username            | string (180) | username              | no       |             |
| usernameCanonical   | string (180) | username_canonical    | no       |             |
| email               | string (180) | email                 | no       |             |
| emailCanonical      | string (180) | email_canonical       | no       |             |
| enabled             | boolean      | enabled               | no       |             |
| salt                | string       | salt                  | yes      |             |
| password            | string       | password              | no       |             |
| lastLogin           | datetime     | last_login            | yes      |             |
| confirmationToken   | string (180) | confirmation_token    | yes      |             |
| passwordRequestedAt | datetime     | password_requested_at | yes      |             |
| roles               | array        | roles                 | no       |             |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Constraint extract example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184200/extract-constraints-form-doctrine-2-entity-in-symfony-2

Comment: Very nice example, thank you! There should be something like this in the Symfony Doctrine Bridge.